# Qual erro com meu script?

Tags: javascript

Sou meio novo com javascript, e tenho esse script aqui:

```js
function mostrar() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("detalhes");
  el[0].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.detalhes {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:mostrar();"><h2>'.$linha['nomep'].'</h2></a>
```

O que está dando errado no meu script? Porque quando eu clico para testar, nada acontece?

Comment: De uma olhada [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: Mas eu queria saber se tem algo de errado com meu script, porque o article "detalhes" não está sendo mostrado?

Comment: Você definiu a classe `show` e a visibilidade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro `getElementsByClassName()` literalmente pegar o elemento pelo nome da classe.

Como você não tem nenhum elemento com a classe `detalhes` logo o retorno da função é um array vazio, portanto o quando você faz `el[0].classList` você esta tentando pegar a propriedade `classList` do item 0, que não existe (lembra que o array esta vazio?), por isso o erro `Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined`, o js não conseguiu ler a propriedade de um objeto vazio/nulo/undefined/inexistente.

Segundo, `toggle("show")`isso faz alternar a classe `show`, ou seja, caso ela não esteja no elemento adiciona, se já estiver, remove. E ela não existe no código que postou.

A classe detalhes tem um `display:none` o que faz "esconder" o elemento, para mostrar ele de novo precisa de tirar o `display:none` poderia ser feito trocando a propriedade diretamente:

```
el[0].style.display = 'block';
```

Ou como no exemplo abaixo, adicionar uma classe css, no caso `show`que vai sobrescrever/anular essa propriedade. O `toggle()` vai adicionar ou remover a classe `show`que faz justamente isso de sobrescrever/anular o `display`do elemento.

Se observar no inspetor de elementos do chrome, vai ver que ela aparece e desaparece confrome o click.

O código corrigido seria assim:

```js
function mostrar() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("detalhes");
  el[0].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.detalhes {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:mostrar();"><h2>'.$linha['nomep'].'</h2></a>

<div class="detalhes">Me achou !!!</div>
```

Comment: Olá amigo! Obrigado por responder. Mas sim, eu já tenho uma div com a classe detalhes assim como no seu exemplo. Eu só não entendi aonde por essa class="show".

Comment: Dei uma editada na resposta explicando um pouso sobre isso.